# Как не использовать "--no-check-certificate" в wget?

Tags: windows, https, ssl

Подскажите, как не использовать `--no-check-certificate` в **Wget** и чтобы не было ни "ERROR" ни "WARNING"? Дело происходит в ОС Windows.

**ERROR**

```
set https_proxy=http://192.168.1.1:80
set use_proxy=on
M:\Distrib\Wget\wget.exe --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=7 --output-file=log.txt --output-document=M:\XML\XMLWMList7.xml
```

`log.txt`:

```
--2015-05-28 07:23:27--  https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=7
Connecting to 192.168.1.1:80... connected.
**ERROR**: cannot verify wm.exchanger.ru's certificate, issued by 'CN=Network Solutions OV Server CA 2,O=Network Solutions L.L.C.,L=Herndon,ST=VA,C=US':
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to wm.exchanger.ru insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

**WARNING**

```
set https_proxy=http://192.168.1.1:80
set use_proxy=on
M:\Distrib\Wget\wget.exe --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --no-check-certificate https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=7 --output-file=log.txt --output-document=M:\XML\XMLWMList7.xml
```

`log.txt`:

```
--2015-05-28 07:26:04--  https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=7
Connecting to 192.168.1.1:80... connected.
**WARNING**: cannot verify wm.exchanger.ru's certificate, issued by 'CN=Network Solutions OV Server CA 2,O=Network Solutions L.L.C.,L=Herndon,ST=VA,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12669 (12K) [text/xml]
Saving to: 'M:/XML/XMLWMList7.xml'

     0K .......... ..                                         100% 46.7K=0.3s

2015-05-28 07:26:05 (46.7 KB/s) - 'M:/XML/XMLWMList7.xml' saved [12669/12669]
```

Comment: В wget можно часто используемые опции выносить в какую-то переменную окружения (не помню точно название).  Тогда не нужно быдет писать эту опцию в командной строке.

Comment: Вы об этом?: `set https_proxy=http://192.168.1.1:80`
`set use_proxy=on` - я так и делаю.

Comment: Нет, я о переменной `WGETRC`, которая указывает на файл, хранящий настройки.

Comment: Интересно. А как сертификат правильно прописать, не **подскажете**?

Comment: а смысл?  просто запишите `--no-check-certificate` в файл параметров

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, во wgetrc оно прописывается несколько не так.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо установить [сертификат издателя](https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/caogc5-network-solutions-ov-server-ca-2) в качестве доверенного сертификата издателя. OpenSSL (библиотека которого используется в `wget`) доверяет сертификатам, установленным в `/etc/ssl/certs`. Сам [сертификат в формате PEM](https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/440ff68a35e03995ac55e457a67eb1680f9a7cdd.pem) надо загрузить в файл с расширением `.crt` и положить в `/etc/ssl/certs`. Этого должно быть достаточно, но если нет, то путь к директории с сертификатами можно указать для `wget` опцией

`--ca-directory=directory`.

Comment: Я не в UNIXе а в WINDOWSе. **1.** Как загрузить файл с расширением `.crt`? **1.1.** В Internet Explorer заходи на сайт - https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=7 -Кликаем замочек - Просмотр сертификатов - Вкладка "Состав" - "Копировать в файл" - "Далее" - А дальше что выбрать? **2.** Как будет выглядеть строка `M:\Distrib\Wget\wget.exe ...` ? Так: `M:\Distrib\Wget\wget.exe --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --ca-directory=M:\Certificate https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=7 --output-file=log.txt --output-document=M:\XML\XMLWMList7.xml` ?

Comment: Перебрал множество вариантов, добавлял `--certificate-type=PEM` , сохранял сертификаты по разному, не получается.

Comment: У `wget` есть ещё опция `--ca-certificate`, с помощью которой можно указать сертификат CA. указывать надо не сам сертификат сайта (тем более что IE сохраняет его в бинарном формате DER, хотя расширение даёт `.crt`). Попробуйте скачать https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/440ff68a35e03995ac55e457a67eb1680f9a7cdd.pem и указать его без переименовывания с опцией `--ca-certificate 440ff68a35e03995ac55e457a67eb1680f9a7cdd.pem`

Comment: Проверил ещё раз много вариантов, один из них: `M:\Distrib\Wget\wget.exe --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --ca-certificate=M:\Certificate\440ff68a35e03995ac55e457a67eb1680f9a7cdd.pem https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=7 --output-file=log.txt --output-document=M:\XML\XMLWMList7.xml` - не получилось. А почему нужно качать сертификат с сайта: https://ssl-tools.net/ а не из сайта: https://wm.exchanger.ru/ ?

Comment: Можно и с wm.exchanger.ru - этот сайт отправляет всю цепочку сертификатов. По описанию `wget` позволяет указать доверенные сертификаты издателей, но не самого сайта. Поэтому вам нужен сертификат этого CA `Network Solutions OV...`, да ещё в PEM формате (IE вам отдаст его в DER). Я сравнил сертификаты из цепочки с сайта и с сайта ssl-tools.net - они одинаковые, и проблема не в них. У меня есть подозрение, что установленный у вас `wget` вообще имеет проблемы с проверкой сертификатов (слишком старая версия библиотеки openssl? - не знаю...)

Comment: Если у вас `wget` из `gnuwin32` c sourceforge.net, то `openssl` там может быть версии `0.9.8h`, а в ней вроде бы не было ещё поддержки `SHA-384`, который используется в подписи сертификата `Network Solutions OV...`.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с отключением проверки сертификатов: создаете файл с именем ".wgetrc", прописываете в нем строку check_certificate = off и кладете этот файл в каталог с wget.exe. Проверено на wget 1.10.2

Answer (score 1):

Добавить комментарий не получилось, наверно у меня был временный аккаунт...

> с именем ".wgetrc"

WINDOWSу не нравится создание, переименование... файла без имени.
Пробовал так:

```
set https_proxy=http://192.168.1.1:80
set use_proxy=on
set check_certificate=off
M:\Distrib\Wget\wget.exe --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=7 --output-file=log.txt --output-document=M:\XML\XMLWMList7.xml
```

Думал `set check_certificate=off` заменит `--no-check-certificate` - **не заменяет**.

**Обновление**

**Egor Skriptunoff** - Не получилось добавить комментарием, мой вопрос уже похоже не мой...

> а смысл? просто запишите `--no-check-certificate` в файл параметров

- `--no-check-certificate` ... Это - почти всегда **плохая идея**, не проверять сертификаты при передаче конфиденциальных или важных данных;
  [ОПЦИИ HTTPS(SSL/TLS)](http://c0ta.org/linux/man-ru/net/wget/src/opt05.html)
- Да, и если возможно избавиться от **WARNING** - почему бы не
  избавиться.

**Обновление 2**

Прошу прощенья, **Outtruder** комментарий добавить не удалось, говорит, репутации маловато.

> У меня есть подозрение, что установленный у вас wget вообще имеет проблемы с проверкой сертификатов (слишком старая версия библиотеки openssl? - не знаю...)

- У Вас отрабатывает скрипт?
- С какими ключами?
- Где Вы Wget качали?

  wget.exe -V >log.txt

**log.txt**

```
GNU Wget 1.16.3 built on mingw32.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file -nls +ntlm +opie -psl +ssl/openssl 

Wgetrc: 
    M:\Distrib\Wget/.wgetrc (user)
    /usr/local/etc/wgetrc (system)
Compile: 
    i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H 
    -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/usr/local/etc/wgetrc" 
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/local/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -I../lib 
    -I/win32dev/misc/wget/out2/include 
    -I/win32dev/misc/wget/out2/include -DNDEBUG -mtune=generic 
    -mtune=intel 
Link: 
    i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -DNDEBUG -mtune=generic -mtune=intel 
    -L/win32dev/misc/wget/out2/lib -L/win32dev/misc/wget/out2/lib 
    /win32dev/misc/wget/out2/lib/libiconv.a 
    /win32dev/misc/wget/out2/lib/libssl.a 
    /win32dev/misc/wget/out2/lib/libcrypto.a -lz -lws2_32 -lole32 
    -lgdi32 -lcrypt32 -lidn ftp-opie.o mswindows.o openssl.o 
    http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a 

Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
```

Файл "**wget-1.16.3-win32.zip**" взял здесь: https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

**На сайте**:
http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ почему то найти не удалось.

Comment: FAR прекрасно работает с файлами "без имени".

Comment: Да нет у меня ни **Ubuntu** ни **FAR**. **Ubuntu** - недавно убрал, не понравилось её следующее название. Вместо **FARа** пользуюсь **Folder Managerом** - переименовал, получилось, но отработало так же как и с `--no-check-certificate`: **WARNING:...** мне не отключить нужно, как отключать я понял, мне нужно, чтобы не было **WARNING**.

Comment: задайте другое имя через `WGETRC`

Comment: В смысле? Другое имя чего именно? Я **Folder Managerом** переименовал в файл **.wgetrc** в файле: `check_certificate=off` в батнике **.cmd** `set https_proxy=http://192.168.1.1:80
set use_proxy=on
M:\Distrib\Wget\wget.exe --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/XMLWMList.asp?exchtype=7 --output-file=log.txt --output-document=M:\XML\XMLWMList7.xml` - **всё работает** но **WARNING**. А вот следующей версии **Ubuntu** я другое имя дать не могу :-)

Comment: Специально скачал и попробовал с парой других сайтов - успешно скачивает при указании сертификата издателя. Не работает именно с сертификатом этого издателя - 'CN=Network Solutions OV Server CA 2,O=Network Solutions L.L.C.,L=Herndon,ST=VA,C=US'

Comment: "**Не работает именно с сертификатом этого издателя...**" А добавление ещё пары ключей не поможет? **1.** Сказать сайту что это не Wget, а какой то браузер. **2.** Манипуляции с куками...